# Can't install windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003

Guys i can't install Win 2003 it's giving me an error not enough space
the screenshot here

[image]

Please direct me to the right path, i'm beginner in Windows Server, thanks.

Comment: does your computer have any existing partitions? Where are you encountering this error? Windows installer? Which stage ?

Comment: And since when did Windows Server 2003 have Aero?  Are you trying to push W2k3 via WDS?

Comment: i do have existing partition for windows 7, and extra NTFS for Win 2003 server, enough memory space, still giving me this error :S

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that NTFS partition is just for this installation, remove the partition entirely & then let the install create it.